# Cite a theorem by its name and number

Tags: theorems

I don't know if this is possible to do in Latex, but here's what I'd like to do. I want to cite a theorem using its label, but what should appear is both its theorem number and its name (the text in square brackets after \begin{theorem}).

For example, consider the following theorem definition:

> \begin{theorem}[Triangle inequality]\label{thm:triangle}
>
> ......
>
> \end{theorem}

When I cite this, I want to be able to write something like

> This is easily proved using the \SomeCommand{thm:triangle}.

What I would like to appear is

> This is easily proved using the Triangle inequality (Theorem 1).

Ideally, the text will also be hyperlinked to the theorem.

Can this be done?

Comment: Have you looked at the `cleveref` package?

Answer (score 9):

Here are two approaches.  First, you can combine `\ref` and `\nameref` to format as desired.  Second, you can use `\mylabel` to save preformatted text.  The advantage of the latter is that it is implemented as a single hyperlink.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}%
  {\newcommand{\mylabel}[2]% #1=name, #2 = contents
    {\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newlabel{#1}{{#2}{\thepage}%
      {\@currentlabelname}{\@currentHref}{}}}}}%
  {\newcommand{\mylabel}[2]% #1=name, #2 = contents
    {\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newlabel{#1}{{#2}{\thepage}}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}[Triangle inequality]\label{thm:triangle}
\mylabel{text:triangle}{Triangle inequality (Theorem \thetheorem)}
\end{theorem}
This is easily proved using the \nameref{thm:triangle} (Theorem \ref{thm:triangle}).

\medskip\noindent
This is easily proved using the \ref{text:triangle}.
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: I expanded the remark about the first solution at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/347100/34551. I think it is much more readable and easier than your second solution, and can be easily adapted to print only a single link.