# Retrieving the title of a theorem, e.g. "My name" from "Lemma 1 (My name)"

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, ntheorem

How can I retrieve the name of a theorem?

I know how to refer to theorems using labels and take the responsibility of giving the title "Theorem" or "Lemma" myself. I also know that packages such as `ntheorem` can go further, and put the name "Theorem" or "Lemma" and then keep the consistency for me. However, I could not find a package that allows me to define a theorem and recover its title.

For example, take the following snippet:

```
\begin{theorem}[Rely-to-Atomic] For any predicate @{term "p"}, and relations @{term "r"}
and @{term "q"}, such that @{term "❙[p,q❙]"} tolerates interference @{term "r"},
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{c}
@{thm (concl) Law_7_4_Rely_To_Atomic_Ref}
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}\label{RTA_Ref}
\end{theorem}
```

After the system processing the funny quotations within @ blocks, this generates the corresponding latex and compiles to:

[image]

What I want is a way of retrieving the string "**Rely-to-Atomic**" from the label `RTA_Ref`. If I have that, I can reference theorems including the title for the convenience of my reader. For example, by typing:

```
Law~\ref{RTA_Ref}~(\nameofthm{RTA_Ref})
```

To obtain:

> Law 3.95 (Rely-to-Atomic)

Since I know that some packages are able to provide a table of theorems, I believe that there should be a way of accessing the title of a theorem or then a package that fits this purpose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301320/cite-a-theorem-by-its-name-and-number/301421?s=5|0.0805#301421

Comment: @DiegoDias: Even if your question might be a duplicate, please consider to accept the answer below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `thmtools` package allows to do that easily:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem{Theorem}
\begin{document}

\begin{Theorem}[My Theorem]\label{thm}
  $1 + 3 = 4$
\end{Theorem}

As we saw in Theorem~\ref{thm} (\nameref{thm})

\end{document}
```

[image: Referring to the Theorem by its name]

You can obtain the same using `amsthm`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}

\begin{thm}[My Theorem]\label{thm}
  $1 + 3 = 4$
\end{thm}

As we saw in Theorem~\ref{thm} (\nameref{thm})

\end{document}
```

Finally, if you want to have a signle link instead of two, you can use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{Theorem}[My Theorem]\label{thm}
  $1 + 3 = 4$
\end{Theorem}

As we saw in \hyperref[thm]{Theorem~\ref*{thm} (\nameref*{thm})}.

\end{document}
```

[image: The same, with a single link.]

And if you don't want any link, just use `\nameref*{thm}`.

I guess you'll be able to adapt the code to print "Law" instead of "Theorem".

Comment: A shame that nobody upvoted this yet (... ;-)) Not even the O.P.!

Comment: Hi Clement, thanks for the answer! I noticed that my preamble includes amsthm. I didn't know that this package was being used to make the magic to happen. Thanks as well for the complement about how to make a single link, instead of two, though I haven't bother much about that :-)

Comment: What if there is no name for the theorem?

Comment: @Peluche Then `\nameref*{thm}` returns nothing and "()" gets displayed.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an additional solution that uses `amsthm` and is indipendent from `hyperref`. It mimics LaTeXs built in cross-ref-routine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newtheorem{law}{Law}

\makeatletter
\let\sv@law\law
\let\sv@label\label
\renewcommand\law[1][]{\sv@law[#1]\def\curr@thmname{#1}}
\renewcommand\label[1]{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \noexpand\global\noexpand\@namedef{#1-thmname}{\curr@thmname}}
  \sv@label{#1}
}
\newcommand\nameofthm[1]{\@nameuse{#1-thmname}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
%Law~\ref{RTA_Ref}~(\nameofthm{RTA_Ref}) 
%
\begin{law}[Rely-to-Atomic]\label{RTA_Ref}
For any predicate $p$, and relations $r$ and $q$, such that $[p,q]$ tolerates interference $r$,
\[
  \mathbf{rely}\,r\cdot[p,q]\sqsubseteq\langle p,q\rangle
\]
\end{law}

...

Law~\ref{RTA_Ref}~(\nameofthm{RTA_Ref})
\end{document}
```

[image: example_rendered]

Comment: That's impressive.

Comment: @Clément -- thx. I think your `thmtools` answer is the prefered way of doing this, tho. +1 for your answer (actually it was 
earlier alredy :)

Comment: This is a quite low level way of achieving that result, I am also impressed. Worth of  being aware of, though I didn't fully understood the details of the solution. I also agree that Clément's answer shall continue as the preferred one, especially because people who may get to the same question would be more likely to be looking for the simplest solution. Thanks!