# Placement parameters for tables and figures in appendix

Tags: floats, positioning, appendices

I would like to know if it exists a way to include a table (or figure) in a section and display it in the appendix, in the following example:

```
\section{section}
stupid text where I speak about a table printed in the appendix

\begin{table}[APPENDIX]
\input{\folder/table.tex}
\end{table}
```

Here I continue my article and then comes something like:

```
\section{Appendix}
here should be my table
```

In this way I will have my tables and figure in the related section and they will be displayed only if I "print the section". They will also appear in the order of inclusion...

Comment: You could have a look at package endfloat.

Comment: You could store it as a macro and expand it in the appendix.  Where you expand it determines the caption number.

Comment: One commonly used trick is to create an elaboarate label (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301320/cite-a-theorem-by-its-name-and-number/301421?s=5|12.9697#301421) and use \ref to print it.  For example, pgfplots can put the legend into a label.  OTOH, this would require things like \string\begin{table}.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Do you an example of macro which can be expanded it in the appendix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shows how to create a macro and a savebox for later use.  Note that the savebox increments the table counter immediately.

This is a demonstration, not a solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\newsavebox{\appboxB}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}

Example text.

\newcommand{\appendA}{%
\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{Macro}
\end{table}%
}

\savebox{\appboxB}{%
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\captionof{table}{Savebox}
\end{minipage}%
}

\appendix
\section{Here}
\appendA
\begin{table}[htp]
\usebox{\appboxB}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

This is a solution.  It saves a list of global macros to be expanded in the appendix.  `\appendset` saves the float, and `\appendlist` expands all of them.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{appendix}
\newcommand{\appendset}[1]% #1 = float to be expanded later
{\stepcounter{appendix}%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname append\theappendix\endcsname{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\appendlist}% expand previously saved floats
{\bgroup
  \count1=0
  \loop\ifnum\count1<\value{appendix}\relax
    \advance\count1 by 1
    \csname append\the\count1\endcsname
  \repeat
\egroup}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}

Example text.

\appendset{%
\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{First}
\end{table}%
}
\appendset{%
\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{Second}
\end{table}%
}

\appendix
\section{Floats}
\appendlist
\end{document}
```

---

With the exception of requiring a `\clearpage` at the start, one can do the same thing using the endfloat package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nolists,noheads,nomarkers]{endfloat}
\renewcommand{\efloatseparator}{\null}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}

Example text.

\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{First}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{Second}
\end{table}

\appendix
\section{Floats}
\clearpage% required
\processdelayedfloats

\section{Optional}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is an interesting solution. Unfortunately it does not work as I would like.  
I have 2 problems with your answer:
1 - once printed table"appboxB" is numerated 1 while table"appendA" has the number 2. I would like them to have their number of appearance.
2 - this solution forces me to print manually the tables and figures in the appendix, which is exactly what I do not want to do. I want them to be printed automatically (only for some chosen graph) in the good order.

Comment: Showing the difference between macros and saveboxes was the point of the demonstration.