# Suspend figures and tables to appendix

Tags: floats, listings, appendices

For my thesis I'm looking to be able to suspend all figures and tables (basically all floatables, but in my case I think I'll only be using figures) to the appendix, where they are all collected together - preferably as a list of figures followed by a list of tables and so on. Also, they should retain the numbering they would have received had they been placed within the text. As I'm using **scrbook** I would like them to retain the chapter-wise numbering, respectively.

**Side note:** I have already experimented with the package **endfloat** [LINK](https://ctan.org/pkg/endfloat?lang=en) that somewhat does what I'd like to have, **but**:
1) places figures & tables at the **end** of the whole document, but I would prefer another place 
2) does produce compiling errors from the second run on that render me unable to compile the document from then on.

## Minimum work example:

For now my file looks something like this (I left most of the packages inside so possible conflicts can be avoided prior to posting an answer. I'm sorry if they clutter the document a bit):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, toc=listof, titlepage, toc=bibliography, open=right, ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style = ieee, urldate =comp, citestyle = numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{tex/mybib.bib}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  andothers   = \mkbibemph{et al\adddot},
  url         = [Online]\adddot\addspace Url:
}
\usepackage[sfdefault,lf]{carlito}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{\carlitoOsF #1}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[margin=12pt,font=sf,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[format=hang,justification=centering,singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
\usepackage[a4paper,inner=3.5cm,outer=2.5cm,includeheadfoot,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage[unicode=true,bookmarks=false,breaklinks=true,colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[toc,style=long,entrycounter,]{glossaries}
\renewcommand*{\glsentrycounterlabel}{}
\makeglossaries
%\loadglsentries[main]{./tex/acronyms}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\begin{document}
\sloppy
\overfullrule=2cm
\pagenumbering{Roman}
The titlepage
\normalsize
\vspace*{10cm}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
% Abstract
Abstract here
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\cleardoubleoddpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
% actual content here
\chapter{My test chapter}
Chapter description
\section{My test section}
Section description
\begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.325\linewidth}
        Figure 1
        \caption{Figure}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{.325\linewidth}
        Figure 1
        \caption{Figure}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \\ \vspace{1cm}
    \begin{subfigure}{.325\linewidth}
        Figure 1
        \caption{Figure}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{.325\linewidth}
        Figure 1
        \caption{Figure}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{.325\linewidth}
        Figure 1
        \caption{Figure}
    \end{subfigure}
    % \hfill
    \caption{Some figures}
\end{figure}
\chapter{Next chapter}
Next chapter description
\section{Next Section}
Next section description
\cleardoubleoddpage
% beginning of appendix
\pagenumbering{Alph}
%
% This is the place where I want my figures to actually appear
%
\printglossary[title={Glossar}]
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

You should find yourself with a thirteen pages long document compiling this with only 3 pages of chapter and figure content (ranging from page 9 to 11). I marked the space where I would want my floatables to be (as if I could write a command there to force it) in the code.

Comment: You can place endfloat using \processdelayedfloats (page 8).  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430603/placement-parameters-for-tables-and-figures-in-appendix.

Comment: @John Kormylo that question is indeed very similar (if not identical) to my question. I experimented with either solutions, but did not receive the result I wanted - which is chapter relative numeration of the floatables. Do you perhaps have another idea of a solution to my problem?

Comment: Since endfloat copies the figure and table source into files (.fff and .ttt), compilation errors probably come from the code itself.  Endfloat appears to use its own counters for the markers, but the captions are all executed together at the end.  One might be able to redefine \thefigure and \thetable to look up previously computed numbers.

Comment: Strangely I just realized that endfloat actually preserves the correct numbering, but I just encountered 2 problems. -- 1 -- figure captions don't support UTF-8 characters (I'm German and wanted to use "ü" in a caption) I cared about the special characters for the normal text though.. with \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} and babel ngerman -- 2 -- get a empty page with only the "Figures" title but no figures on it because latex places all figures on "floatables-only-pages" :( do you have any advice?

Comment: Sorry, I use ASCII.  BTW, you are loading caption twice.

Comment: @mgessenich The UTF-8 bug should be fixed with version 2.6 of the `endfloat` package. Which version are you using?

Comment: @mgessenich Regarding the numbering: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406831/force-floats-to-end-of-pdf-but-keep-numbering-per-chapter-two-versions-of-docu

Comment: @John you're right I fixed the duplicate. Still, loading package endfloat I suddenly get errors from using äöüß in my figure captions... --- AxelSommerfeldt thx. I came to a nearly working solution with endfloat with only 1 flaw left.. the page headers ( top left and top right ) are named in English (Figures), but I would like to have the German version.. does any of you know how to fix those?

Comment: @mgessenich Use `\renewcommand\figuresection{Abbildungen}` after loading the `endfloat` package. See also section 4 of the `endfloat` manual. Regarding the Umlaute: What version of the endfloat package are you using? I have no problems adding ÄÖÜäöüß to the captions of your example document above.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt I have to admin I did not read the entire manual, thx. Good point, I found out, that I was using a quite old version (2011/12/25) and will upgrade that now and try again

Comment: Alright.. figure captions done.. but I just realized that the numbering of my figures is indeed NOT solved, but they get labeled as if they belong to my last chapter (in this case 3).. did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

In the following, just using endfloat will cause the caption numbers to use the current chapter number (in this case, 2.1 instead of 1.1).  The macro `\savecaptionof` needs to go after each figure or table.  `\restorecaptionof` redefines `\thefigure` or `\thetable` to use these stored values.

I'm not sure what `\label` will do, but with one figure per page it should work fine.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, toc=listof, titlepage, toc=bibliography, 

open=right, ngerman]{scrbook}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% ASCII here
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style = ieee, urldate =comp, citestyle = numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{tex/mybib.bib}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  andothers   = \mkbibemph{et al\adddot},
  url         = [Online]\adddot\addspace Url:
}
\usepackage[sfdefault,lf]{carlito}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{\carlitoOsF #1}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[margin=12pt,font=sf,labelfont=bf,format=hang,justification=centering,singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
\usepackage[a4paper,inner=3.5cm,outer=2.5cm,includeheadfoot,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage[unicode=true,bookmarks=false,breaklinks=true,colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[toc,style=long,entrycounter,]{glossaries}
\renewcommand*{\glsentrycounterlabel}{}
\makeglossaries
%\loadglsentries[main]{./tex/acronyms}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{endfloat}

\newcommand{\savecaptionof}[1]% #1 = figure or table (counter)
{%
  \refstepcounter{#1}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname #1\arabic{#1}\endcsname{\csname the#1\endcsname}% store as \figure1 etc.
}
\newcommand{\restorecaptionof}[1]% #1 = figure or table (counter)
{%
  \setcounter{#1}{0}%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname the#1\endcsname{\csname #1\arabic{#1}\endcsname}%
}

\begin{document}
\sloppy
\overfullrule=2cm
\pagenumbering{Roman}
The titlepage
\normalsize
\vspace*{10cm}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
% Abstract
Abstract here
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\cleardoubleoddpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
% actual content here
\chapter{My test chapter}
Chapter description
\section{My test section}
Section description
\begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.325\linewidth}
        Figure 1
        \caption{Figure}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{.325\linewidth}
        Figure 1
        \caption{Figure}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \\ \vspace{1cm}
    \begin{subfigure}{.325\linewidth}
        Figure 1
        \caption{Figure}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{.325\linewidth}
        Figure 1
        \caption{Figure}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{.325\linewidth}
        Figure 1
        \caption{Figure}
    \end{subfigure}
    % \hfill
    \caption{Some figures}
\end{figure}
\savecaptionof{figure}% goes immediately after figure or table

\chapter{Next chapter}
Next chapter description
\section{Next Section}
Next section description
\cleardoubleoddpage
% beginning of appendix
\pagenumbering{Alph}
%
% This is the place where I want my figures to actually appear
\restorecaptionof{figure}% goes before \processdelayedfloats
\processdelayedfloats
%
\printglossary[title={Glossar}]
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Currently I'm not able to compile your answer.. I commented out the bib, but it still has lots of errors. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I commented out inputenc, since I don't need it with my editor, and fontenc gives me errors whenever I try to use it.

Comment: Commenting in inputenc did not solve all the problems :( lots of "Missing \endcsname inserted" and " Extra \endcsname" and a "Paragraph ended before \@fileswith@ptions was complete" .. suggestions?

Comment: I tried out to add the \newcommand definitions and the \restorecaptionof{figure} at the end, but I receive lots of "Undefined control sequence" errors.. in the logfile it compains about "\efloatseparator" ..

Comment: I do not advice commenting out inputenc if your editor produces utf8.  My editor doesn't, and I normally don't use xelatex.