# Place all figures last without changing numbering

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

I have a question regarding the topic: [Place all floats last without changing numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3491/place-all-floats-last-without-changing-numbering)

How can I modify the solution so that it works for figures, inclusive a List of Figures? I have tried the package `endfloat` for my figures but have encountered certain issues hence why I am looking for an alternative way of putting all my figures in a separate Chapter at the end of my document but before the supplement.

Is there a possibility to include multiple figures in format of a table?

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lc}
%Input image&
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}&
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}\\
%Aligned face&
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}&
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}\\
\end{tabular}}{Fifth image}{fig:tabfig}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: For figures and tables, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430603/placement-parameters-for-tables-and-figures-in-appendix/430900?r=SearchResults&s=2|22.9245#430900 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439236/suspend-figures-and-tables-to-appendix/440069?r=SearchResults&s=3|18.9709#440069

Comment: Ad *"Is there a possibility to include multiple figures in format of a table?"* Seems your code-snippet creates a single figure consisting of a table (created via the tabular-environment) containing several images. Please specify precisely what you need: Do you need a sequence of floating objects? Is "floating" not needed but you just need a series of images with captions (see the “caption outside float” facility of the package "caption"), probably arranged in terms of a tablar/longtable-environment?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

**UPDATE** Begin numbering the figures with .1 in each section.

[image: f]

[image: g]

Move all the figures to the end using the command `figfrom` (one optional parameter and three mandatory:
`#1` (opt) figure configuration, `#2` figure name, `#3` caption, `#4` label) within the environment `fromsection{<section number of the figures>}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}    

%%*****************  adapted from <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%%  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3491/place-all-floats-last-without-changing-numbering
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\newcounter{savesection}
\newenvironment{fromsection}[1]{% #1 section number
    \setcounter{figure}{0}%
    \setcounter{savesection}{\value{section}}%
    \setcounter{section}{#1}%
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}}
{\setcounter{section}{\value{savesection}}}

\newcommand{\figfrom}[4][]{% #1 (opt) figure specs, #2 figure name, #3 caption, #4 label
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
    \caption{#3}
    \label{#4}
\end{figure}
}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}
%% ***************************************** 

\begin{document}
    
    \listoffigures
    
    \section{Introduction}
    Please see figures~\ref{fig:one} and \ref{fig:two} in section~\ref{app:allimg}.
    
    \section{Other stuff}
    See also figure~\ref{fig:three} on page~\pageref{fig:three}.        

    \section{All figures together}\label{app:allimg}
    
    \begin{fromsection}{1}
        \figfrom[width=50pt]{example-image-a}{First image}{fig:one}
        \figfrom[scale=0.5]{example-image-b}{Second image}{fig:two}
    \end{fromsection}
    
    \begin{fromsection}{2}
        \figfrom[height=270pt]{example-image-c}{Third image}{fig:three}
    \end{fromsection}

    \appendix
    \section{Supplement}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: The numbering is 1.1, 1.2, 2.3. - How do I change the code to obtain 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, so that the numbering starts with .1 for each section? Otherwise, your code works great! Thanks, Simon!

Comment: @KMFWeb In the definition of the environment `fromsection` behind `\setcounter{section}{#1}%` add `\setcounter{figure}{0}%`. If using **hyperref**, which must be loaded _after_ the package **float**, ensure uniqueness of destination-names by also adding `\renewcommand{\theHsection}{\arabic{section}}` and after `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}` adding `\renewcommand{\theHfigure}{\theHsection.\arabic{figure}}`. With `fromsection` you may wish to add restoring the `figure`-counter at the end of the environment in the same way in which the `section`-counter is restored.

Comment: @KMFWeb Please see the updated code to correct the figure numbers. You can follow Ulrich Diez's very good instructions for adding hyperlinks if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain a stack where tokens for creating floats are accumulated.

In the example below

- a token-stack is created via `\NewStack{⟨macro⟩}`.
- tokens are appended to a token-stack via `\AppendToStack{⟨macro⟩}{⟨tokens⟩}`.
- the tokens saved in a stack are "flushed" and the stack is emptied via `\FlushAndClearStack{⟨macro⟩}`.
- the command

  ```
  \StuffAndCountersToStack{⟨macro⟩}%
                        {⟨counters to step at the time of carrying out \StuffAndCountersToStack⟩}%
                        {⟨counters to reset and restore at the time of delivering the ⟨tokens⟩⟩}%
                        {⟨tokens⟩}%
  ```

  adds to the stack *⟨macro⟩*

  - directive to open a local scope
  - directives to reset *⟨counters to reset and restore at the time of delivering the *⟨tokens⟩*⟩*,
  - directives to reset \the*⟨counter⟩* and \theH*⟨counter⟩* of *⟨counters to reset and restore at the time of delivering the *⟨tokens⟩*⟩*,
  - directives to adjust \the*⟨counter⟩* and \theH*⟨counter⟩* of *⟨counters to step at the time of carrying out \StuffAndCountersToStack⟩*
  - *⟨tokens⟩*
  - directives to restore *⟨counters to reset and restore at the time of delivering the *⟨tokens⟩*⟩*,
  - directive to close the local scope

  and steps *⟨counters to step at the time of carrying out \StuffAndCountersToStack⟩*.
- the command

  ```
  \VerbatimToScantokensStuffAndCountersToStack{⟨macro⟩}%
                        {⟨counters to step at the time of carrying out \StuffAndCountersToStack⟩}%
                        {⟨counters to reset and restore at the time of delivering the ⟨verbatimized material⟩ via \scantokens⟩}%
                        |⟨verbatimized material⟩|%
  ```

  does almost the same as the command `\StuffAndCountersToStack`. The difference is: The *⟨tokens⟩*-argument is read and tokenized in verbatim-catcode-régime and therefore called *⟨verbatimized material⟩*. Instead of just adding *⟨tokens⟩* to the stack *⟨macro⟩*, directives are added to the stack *⟨macro⟩* to pass *⟨verbatimized material⟩* to `\scantokens`.

```latex
\makeatletter
% With older LaTeX-releases uncomment the following line:
%\RequirePackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\@ifdefinable\MapCommaListToMacro{%
  \let\MapCommaListToMacro=\clist_map_function:nN 
}%
\ExplSyntaxOff
\@ifdefinable\stopromannumeral{\chardef\stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
\newcommand\unexpandedlocalsetcounter[1]{%
  \unexpanded{\localsetcounter{#1}}{\number\value{#1}}%
  \def\expandafter\noexpand\csname theH#1\endcsname{\csname theH#1\endcsname}%
  \def\expandafter\noexpand\csname the#1\endcsname{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
}%
\newcommand\unexpandedadjustcounter[1]{%
  \def\expandafter\noexpand\csname theH#1\endcsname{\csname theH#1\endcsname}%
  \def\expandafter\noexpand\csname the#1\endcsname{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
}%
\newcommand\unexpandedsetcounter[1]{%
  \unexpanded{\setcounter{#1}}{\number\value{#1}}%
}%
\@ifdefinable\localsetcounter{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand\localsetcounter[2]{%
    \csname c@#1\endcsname=#2\relax
  }%
}%
\@ifdefinable\localstepcounter{%
  \newcommand\localstepcounter[1]{%
    \advance\csname c@#1\endcsname by 1 %
  }%
}%
\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
%
% If this was for a package, checking whether stack-macro is defined
% could be implemented for the sake of error-checking.
\NewDocumentCommand\NewStack{m}{\newcommand#1{}}%
\NewDocumentCommand\FlushAndClearStack{m}{#1\global\let#1\empty}%
\NewDocumentCommand\AppendToStack{mm}{\xdef#1{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1#2}}}%
\newcommand\StuffAndCountersToStack[4]{%
  \@bsphack
  \begingroup
  \protected@edef\@tempa{\MapCommaListToMacro{#3}{\unexpandedlocalsetcounter}}%
  \MapCommaListToMacro{#2}{\localstepcounter}%
  \protected@edef\@tempb{\MapCommaListToMacro{#2}{\unexpandedadjustcounter}}%
  \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
    \romannumeral
    \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\expandafter{\expandafter\begingroup
    \romannumeral\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\stopromannumeral\expandafter
     \@tempa\@tempb#4}}{%
       \stopromannumeral
       \begingroup
       \protected@edef\@tempa{\MapCommaListToMacro{#3}{\unexpandedsetcounter}}%
       \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\@tempa}%
    }%
    \endgroup
  }{\AppendToStack{#1}}%
  \MapCommaListToMacro{#2}{\stepcounter}%
  \@esphack
}%
%=== \VerbatimToScantokensStuffAndCountersToStack ========================
\NewDocumentCommand\VerbatimToScantokensStuffAndCountersToStack{mmm}{%
  \@bsphack
  \begingroup
  \catcode`\^^I=12\relax
  \InnerVerbatimToScantokensStuffAndCountersToStack{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}%
\begingroup
\def\InnerVerbatimToScantokensStuffAndCountersToStack#1{%
  \endgroup
  \NewDocumentCommand\InnerVerbatimToScantokensStuffAndCountersToStack{mmm+v}{%
    \endgroup
    \expandafter\@gobble\StuffAndCountersToStack{##1}{##2}{##3}{%
      \begingroup\newlinechar=\endlinechar
      \scantokens{\endgroup##4#1}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\catcode`\%=12\relax
\InnerVerbatimToScantokensStuffAndCountersToStack{%}%
%=== End of code of \VerbatimToScantokensStuffAndCountersToStack =========
\makeatother

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
% Load hyperref _after_ float !
\usepackage{hyperref}

\NewStack{\laterfloats}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{theHfigure}{}{%
  \renewcommand{\theHfigure}{\theHsection.\arabic{figure}}%
}%
\csname @addtoreset\endcsname{figure}{section}

% \ref without hyperlink:
\csname @ifpackageloaded\endcsname{hyperref}{%
  \newcommand*\myref{\ref*}%
}{%
  \newcommand*\myref{\ref}%
}%

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section*{Introduction}
Please see figure~\ref{fig:one} and \ref{fig:two} and \ref{fig:three}
and \ref{fig:four} in Appendix~\ref{app:allimg}.

\section{First section}
Delayed figure~\ref{fig:one} and delayed figure~\ref{fig:two} are defined in this section.

\StuffAndCountersToStack{\laterfloats}{figure}{section,figure}{%
  \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=50pt]{example-image-a}%
    \caption{First image}%
    \label{fig:one}%
  \end{figure}%
}%

\StuffAndCountersToStack{\laterfloats}{figure}{section,figure}{%
  \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-b}%
    \caption{Second image}%
    \label{fig:two}%
  \end{figure}%
}%

\section{Second section}
Delayed figure~\ref{fig:three} is defined in this section.

\VerbatimToScantokensStuffAndCountersToStack{\laterfloats}%
                                            {figure}%
                                            {section,figure}%
                                            ?%<-start of verbatim-argument
  \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
    \hline\\
    \begin{minipage}{.27\textwidth}
% Indenting of source code does matter with verbatimized arguments!
\begin{verbatim*}
1 AB % & _^~# } {
2 AB % & _^~# } {
\end{verbatim*}
    \end{minipage}
    \\\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{figure with verbatim}%
    \label{fig:three}%
  \end{figure}%
? %<-end of verbatim-argument

\section{Third section}
Delayed figure~\ref{fig:four} is defined in this section.

\StuffAndCountersToStack{\laterfloats}{figure}{section,figure}{%
  \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=240pt]{example-image-c}%
    \caption{Third image}%
    \label{fig:four}%
  \end{figure}%
}%

\appendix

\section{An appendix}\label{app:a}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
A figure in appendix \myref{app:a}
\caption{A figure in appendix \myref{app:a}}
\end{figure}

\subsection{A subsection of appendix \myref{app:a}}\label{app:allimg}

Here come all the delayed floats.

\FlushAndClearStack{\laterfloats}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

---

I suppose it would be only a few lines in expl3, but I am not yet so fluent in expl3 that I could type the appropriate expl3 code in a few minutes.

There are many expl3-luminaries here, whom I could not hold a candle and who would of the cuff do a much better job than I could do by fiddling around and reading interface3.pdf for hours.
But I "borrowed" expl3's  `\clist_map_function:nN` for mapping elements of comma-lists as arguments to macros. ;-)
(I also have my own "old school code" for this sort of things, but pasting that here would imply another huge load of confusing code.)